# Proper way of using EntityManager find and refresh

Tags: jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I use JPA in EJB project.

```
@EJB
UserDAO userDAO;

public User findUserById(int id){
    User user = userDAO.find(id); //em.find
    userDAO.refresh(user); //em.refresh
    return user;
}
```

Is that correct? I want to refresh to get actual size of collection in `User`, is that ok to do that ? or should I make another function to check that collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do `refresh`, it does not bring any benefit here. The user after `find` should contain already all required info.

If you do not get expected size, it could be because the other operation what modifies the collection have not yet committed transaction or something else, it much depends what you have there.

Comment: When I add some items to User's collection and then use `find` on User I still get old size in User object. I think that is from JPA cache or something. With `refresh` here it works ok. 
Is that ok to use refresh like that ? (only here with User I have that problem) or is it abuse of JPA?

Comment: I think it is ok, probably your cache misconfigured